# C++-based make system

Tags: c++, build, makefile

Are there any build systems that don't use a DSL but actually use C++ as the build language?

Comment: Are you asking if any c++ compiler were written in c++? I'm not aware of any in particular, but it's not at all inconceivable.

Comment: Sorry.  No, I asking for a build system like make, except the build language is C++ *itself* (not a scripting language like python or some custom recursive language, just actual C++).  So, for example a .cpp file would contain all the build rules, perhaps as an object, then you would simply compile the .cpp file, run it, and it would build the project.

Comment: Why not just make your own Python script?

Comment: @Ken Wayne Vanderlinde - I'd say that clang++ counts as a C++ compiler written in C++. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a build system that I use in my projects in Python called [pybake](http://code.google.com/p/pybake/). It's designed to be a bit smarter than make, with less magic. The build is also defined in Python, thereby reusing an existing language, rather than generating a new DSL for that purpose. Here's an [example](http://code.google.com/p/cpfs/source/browse/make.py) of it in use.

Comment: Cool.  Just finished doing my own in C++ and it works fine so far across linux and windows targets.  Just finished the part that generates project files.  It does have a couple of good points too.  First of all, it's *debuggable* (how many make scripts are easily debugged?), and secondly I can use intellisense on it, so it's actually faster and more flexible than typing up a bunch of cmake files. Not nearly as full-featured as other make systems, but it suits my needs for now.

Answer (score 11):

Yo Dawg, I heard you like C++, so I added C++ to your build system, so you have to compile before you compile.

Comment: For those of you that keep flagging this answer as not an answer, I need a reason.  Quirky though it is, it does in fact seem to answer the question asked.

Comment: So you added C++ to what exactly? Perhaps a link to a website would be good.

Answer (score 3):

None that are popular, if anyone was crazy enough to even write one.  C++ would be an incredibly clumsy language for that.

If you're looking to create one, instead pick a language such as Python or Lua in order to use something popular and not invent a new DSL.

Comment: Aren't most DSL's new inventions?  Isn't that the purpose of a DSL?

Comment: Well the advantage is that you wouldn't need to require any build system with your project.  It would just bootstrap itself.

Comment: @jjacksonRIAB: If you have a C++ compiler available (which you'd need to have to compile your initial C++), then you will more likely than not have some form of make or command shell available.  Using either of those and dealing with platform differences in them will be much easier than writing a build system in C++.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this.  I'm not really saying it would be terribly useful or practical; more that it would be somewhat interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking if there are any build systems, like Make or Ant that use C++ code as the directives rather than specialized commands?  While many higher level languages have such a system, there aren't any in C++ that I am aware of.  Certainly not the popular ones.  This is probably because C++ is a compiled language and not one that is trivial to parse.  This makes it less suitable for what is essentially a lightweight scripting task.

Comment: Well I'm aware of all the popular build languages, I use CMake currently.  I don't really see why a separate parser would be needed.  Basically what I mean is something like: g++ Makefile.cpp, it uses c++ as a build language, produces an executable, then you run that and it builds everything within that Makefile.cpp file, not using a separate language - it just bootstraps itself off of that one file and whatever other files it can include.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably C++ code in there somewhere but if you mean you would have to write a C++ program and compile it then run it to build a different source tree, I don't think that would really work in the scheme of things. What would you build your build script with? It goes on and on.

Compilers and the commands behind the scripting languages are often written in C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ is compiled, this would give you the problem of needing a build system for your C++-based build system. I am not aware of any C++-based build system and would be surprised to find one. For interpreted languages like Python, bootstrapping isn't an issue (and so you will find scons, for example).

If you are looking for something better than Make, though, check out [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). Though somewhat out-of-date, you may find the [C++ Project Template](http://code.google.com/p/cpp-project-template/) helpful as an example for creating CMake-based projects.

Comment: "problem of needing a build system for your build system" Why is that really a problem? E.g. Autotools is built using make.

Comment: I haven't used Scons (I've used nmake, make, cmake, qmake), but wouldn't you have to download Python so that it can bootstrap itself?

Comment: @jjacksonRIAB, no, scons is used to install Python packages... not the original installation of Python, itself. Also, it's common for UNIX systems to have Python pre-installed.

Comment: @kotlinksi, yes, you could use a different build system for your build system, although then things are just getting a bit ridiculous.